# How do I change text to the end of a select option’s text?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how I can change a part of the text of the options of a select.
I have a currency exchange calculator, and depending on the chosen currency, I should dynamically change the amount and name of the currency at the end of the movie name.

I have used  but I don't know if it is the best option. The title of the film must always remain the same

```
<div class="movie-container">
        <label>Pick a movie:</label>
        <select id="movie">
            <option value="10">Once Upon a Time <span class="replace">12 USD</span></option>
            <option value="12">Pulp Fiction <span class="replace">10 USD</span></option>
            <option value="8">Reservoir Dogs <span class="replace">9 USD</span></option>
            <option value="9">Django: Unchained <span class="replace">8USD</span></option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

When a user chooses another to the dropdown, for example the Euro, the code should look like this:

```
<div class="movie-container">
            <label>Pick a movie:</label>
            <select id="movie">
                <option value="10,8">Once Upon a Time <span class="replace">10,8 EUR</span></option>
                <option value="8,9">Pulp Fiction <span class="replace">8,9 EUR</span></option>
                <option value="7,6">Reservoir Dogs <span class="replace">7,6 EUR</span></option>
                <option value="6,8">Django: Unchained <span class="replace">6,8 EUR</span></option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Any ideas? Which selector should I use? You should change the number and currency code. I am using Fetch with the exchangerate-api.com API

Thanks !!

Comment: I would store that HTML as a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and, when the API call is complete update the expressions in it (e.g `${price}`) with the returned data.

Comment: @Andy You can't store a template literal as a template, the variables are replaced when you create the literal.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't quite clear. I would have a function that is called with arguments passed in from the API data, and that would return the updated literal.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the API returns some dictionary of conversion rates, below is a working solution. Note that according to [current HTML5 specifications](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-option-element), the `option` element can only contain text if it has no label and is a child of a `select` element.

```js
let rates = {
    "USD": 1,
  "Euro": 0.86,
  "GBP": 0.74
}

let oldUnit = "USD";

document.getElementById("currencyPicker").onchange = function(e) {
    let newUnit = document.getElementById("currencyPicker").value;
  document.querySelectorAll(".movieOption").forEach((movie) => {
    let newValue = movie.value * rates[newUnit] / rates[oldUnit];
    let newText = `${movie.dataset.title} ${newValue.toFixed(2)} ${newUnit}`
    movie.textContent = newText;
    movie.value = newValue;
  });
  oldUnit = newUnit;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Pick a currency:</label>
  <select id="currencyPicker">
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="Euro">Euro</option>
    <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="movie-container">
  <label>Pick a movie:</label>
  <select id="movie">
    <option data-title="Once Upon a Time" class="movieOption" value="12">Once Upon a Time 12.00 USD</option>
    <option data-title="Pulp Fiction" class="movieOption" value="10">Pulp Fiction 10.00 USD</option>
    <option data-title="Reservoir Dogs" class="movieOption" value="9">Reservoir Dogs 9.00 USD</option>
    <option data-title="Django: Unchained" class="movieOption" value="8">Django: Unchained 8.00 USD</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The title is held in the `data-title` attribute, and is used to format the `textContent` of each option element. The new value is displayed to 2 decimal places.

Comment: It seems like a very good Wahoowa solution!
Now I have the problem with the Fetch, to be able to store the rates and be able to use them later...

(this should replace the first let of your code)

function dataCurrency(){

    const currencySelected = currencySelect.value;
    
    fetch(`https://api.exchangerate-api.com/v4/latest/${currencySelected}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {

        let rates = data.rates;
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}

currencySelect.addEventListener('change', dataCurrency);

Answer (score 0):

If `option` is the current option being updated, `new_price` is the recalculated price, and `currency` is the new currency, you can do:

```
option.value = new_price;
option.querySelector(".replace").innerText = `${new_price} ${currency}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following code will help you out.

```
window.onload = function(){
const currency = document.getElementById('currency');
const movieContainer = document.getElementById('movie');

// on currency change event you will get the selected index.
currency.onchange = function(){

const sCurrency = this.selectedIndex;
const currencyArray = [{name: 'US', isNow: 100},
{name: 'EU', isNow: 20}];


let selectedItem = currencyArray.find((item,index) => index === this.selectedIndex);

/* console.log(movieContainer) */

    for(let i=0; i<movieContainer.options.length; i++) {
      
    console.log(movieContainer.options[i])
        // this will gives you the outer html
      console.log(movieContainer.options[i].outerHTML)
      // this will give you the innerText
      console.log(movieContainer.options[i].innerText)
    }
    }
}
```

The above example is simple as per your needs currency drop down and on change of each time you get the currency and utilize the currency api(for that). Then you can get the desired content of the next drop down.